# How can i add cookie in headers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests

i want to automation testing tool using api.
at first, i login the site and get a cookie.

my code is python3

```
import urllib
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url ='http://ip:port/api/login'
login_req = urllib.parse.urlencode(login_form)
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r= http.request('POST',url,fields={'userName':'id','password':'passoword'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.data.decode('utf-8'),'lxml')
cookie = r.getheaders().get('Set-Cookie')
str1 = r.getheaders().get('Set-Cookie')
str2 = 'JSESSIONID' +str1.split('JSESSIONID')[1]
str2 = str2[0:-2]
print(str2)
 -- JSESSIONID=df0010cf-1273-4add-9158-70d817a182f7; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

and then, i add cookie on head another web site api.
but it is not working!

```
url2 = 'http://ip:port/api/notebook/job/paragraph'
r2 = http.request('POST',url2)
r2.headers['Set-Cookie']=str2
r2.headers['Cookie']=str2
http.request('POST',url2, headers=r2.headers)
```

why is not working? it shows another cookie
if you know this situation, please explain to me..
error contents is that.

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /api/login;JSESSIONID=b8f6d236-494b-4646-8723-ccd0d7ef832f. 
Reason: Server Error
Caused by:</h3><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Filtered request failed. 
ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('<html>\n',))
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Generally error codes starting with `5` are raised due to problem from the website. I don't think there's anything wrong with your code if you're getting `HTTP ERROR 500`. Refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Thanks.. i find another solution to solve it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `requests` module in python 3.x. You have to create a session which you are not doing now that's why you are facing problems.

```
import requests
s=requests.Session()
url ='http://ip:port/api/login'
r=s.get(url)
dct=s.cookies.get_dict() #it will return cookies(if any) and save it in dict
```

Take which ever cookie is wanted by the server and all the headers requested and pass it in header

```
jid=dct["JSESSIONID"]
head = {JSESSIONID="+jid,.....}
payload = {'userName':'id','password':'passoword'}
r = s.post(url, data=payload,headers=head)
r = s.get('whatever url after login')
```

To get info about which specific headers you have to pass and all the parameters  required for POST

  Open link in google chrome.

  Open Developers Console(fn + F12).

  There search for login doc (if cannot find, input wrong details and submit).

  You will get info about request headers and POST parameters.

Comment: i try to this.. but last r is not working..kkkk... response[500] error

Comment: login is okay
and i add a jsession in header  that is fine.
but last post api is not working

Comment: can you give me the link where you are trying to POST?

Comment: web site is my cooperation's web site.. so i don't give it.. sorry

Comment: Ok, no problem, but usually this code works fine and you can login into any website with this

Comment: Thxs a lot !!  .. i find another solution to solve this!

Comment: dct= s.cookies.get_dict()
jid = dct['JSESSIONID'] 
head ={'Cookies':'JSESSIONID ='+ jid +' Path=/; HttpOnly'}
r1= s.post(url,data=postdata,headers=head)
It is a answer~~
I find it !